# Aliasing resellers domain to primary domain

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content

I have designed a website that accepts re-sellers and actually the concept of this website is having local re-sellers for each province (or should we say branches).

I have designed this website in a way that anybody who has a domain, can point to our website (a record or cname). well most of the website content are the same, the only difference is that re-sellers website doesn't have some items on the main menu and may have some small descriptions of their own branch in some pages.

I read that Google may ban websites with duplicate content (or which are significantly similar). I want to know will this be a problem for me?

If yes, what else can I do? we have had considered asking our reseller to use iframe that loads our website but wanted that each reseller can have its own SEO and try harder but what I read about this duplicate thing worries me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is blatent duplicate content which is exactly what Google doesn't want. So, yes, this will get you in trouble. Your only real option is to use canonical URLs for all of those pages but that means your resellers' websites will never show up in Google's search results. If your resellers are ok with that, then you're all set. But if you're selling these reseller websites being found in search as a perk then you need to find a new perk to replace this one with. Otherwise your site will e penalized, too, and that's the worst case scenario for you.

Comment: what would you suggest? iframes are not nice. do you have any other  suggestions? do you even suggest using iframes?

Comment: You don't have any good SEO options. If you don't use canonical URLs you risk being severely penalized. What you're trying to do is something Google really wants to keep out of their search results.

Comment: well what I mean, resellers want to have their own websites. do you suggest we use iframes for our resellers, tell them to use iframe to load our website

Comment: No. You risk duplicate content if you do. Iframes are generally not search engine friendly but they may already crawl them and may get better at it as time progresses. Putting content in there to hide it from them is not a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

As John said, this is blatant duplicate content. The only viable option I can see is giving the resellers the site without desciptions and let each of them write their own descriptions for each item. If they don't do that, none of the sites will be found because they will all get penalized.